# Function composition of fmap

Tags: haskell

The simple definition of function composition is:

```
f ( g x)
```

or

```
(f . g) $ x
```

Now I have following example:

```
  newtype Compose f g a =
    Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

  instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ (fmap . fmap) f fga
```

Then I try to write `fmap` without composition operator as:

```
  instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ fmap f (fmap f fga)
```

and the compiler complains:

```
* Couldn't match type `b' with `g b'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
    at D:\haskell\chapter25\src\Twinplicative.hs:11:5
  Expected type: f (g b)
    Actual type: f b
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `fmap f (fmap f fga)'
  In the expression: Compose $ fmap f (fmap f fga)
  In an equation for `fmap':
      fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ fmap f (fmap f fga)
* Relevant bindings include
    fga :: f (g a)
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter25\src\Twinplicative.hs:11:21)
    f :: a -> b
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter25\src\Twinplicative.hs:11:10)
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter25\src\Twinplicative.hs:11:5)
```

How to compose `fmap` above without composition operator?

Comment: `fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ fmap (fmap f) fga`

Comment: You didn't actually give a definition of function composition. I suspect that if you had, you could have applied it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you provide to the leftmost application of `fmap` should have type `g a -> g b` while you are providing `f` which has type `a -> b`. You can lift a function `a -> b` to `g a -> g b` using `fmap` i.e. `fmap f`. The second argument to the outer `fmap` should have type `f (g a)` which is the type of `fga`:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ fmap (fmap f) fga
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Lee's answer, which states clearly how you could implement the `Functor` instance for `Compose` yourself from scratch. However, I also thought it worth answering a closely related question, which is: how do I start from the existing instance and mechanically rewrite it to avoid the `(.)` function composition? Therefore I tackle that question in this answer.

Since `(f . g) x = f (g x)` is the defining equation of `(.)`, we conclude `(fmap . fmap) f = fmap (fmap f)`. Applying both sides of the equation to `fga`, we get:

```
(fmap . fmap) f fga = fmap (fmap f) fga
```